# Explain Henri Bergson's stance on Time and Space?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, positivism

I understand that he was, in general, a positivist or realist thinker; however, I am confused when he begins to talk about time existing as two points (A and B) and its differences from a determinist's perspective of time as a mathematical property, or scientific paradox. Could someone help?

Comment: It might be worth quoting the text. My understanding of Bergson is vague - but I think he's far from being a realist/positivist.

Answer (score 1):

> According to Bergson, there are two kinds of time, homogeneous and
>   heterogeneous. The latter is the time of our experience, and is named
>   by him '*la durée*,' to which no English expression exactly
>   corresponds. Homogeneous time, which is what we ordinarily mean when
>   we use the word time, is, in his view, space, on to which the mind
>   merely projects psychological time, the succession of our conscious
>   states, thus making it appear to be a successive and continuous
>   reality. In fact, it is nothing but an illusion for there is no true
>   succession in things which are said to be measured by time, since one
>   state has entirely disappeared when another appears. So he writes : '
>   Doubtless exterior things change, but their moments only succeed one
>   another with respect to a consciousness which remembers them. We
>   observe outside us, at any given moment, a collection of simultaneous
>   positions ; nothing remains of the former simultaneities.' [*[Essai sur
>   les donnes de la conscience](http://www.worldcat.org/title/essai-sur-les-donnes-immediates-de-la-conscience/oclc/255701998)*, p. 173.]
>
> Hence, the only time which is not illusory, and which he regards as
>   real, is the heterogeneous time, or succession, which accompanies the
>   development of our conscious states. Such development is purely
>   qualitative, and its parts can only be qualitatively, never
>   quantitatively, distinguished, so that they are absolutely
>   heterogeneous; for it is clear that all our psychic acts are
>   unextended — it is impossible to have a yard of thought — and so if
>   distinct their distinction can be qualitative only.
>
> There can be no question as to the subjective character of this
>   theory; and to make of time an affection of our conscious states is to
>   contradict completely the commonsense notion of it, which undoubtedly
>   attaches it to bodies. What is more, it is only the permanent which
>   changes, and the permanent endures: so that it is inconsistent to
>   admit that things change and to deny their duration. Moreover, if time
>   attaches only to our conscious states, each one of us will live in his
>   own time, and there will be no unique sense in which two events can be
>   said to be simultaneous. This, however, is to deny time, not to
>   explain it, for the notion of time surely implies, at least, the
>   possibility of comparing the position of two events in the world
>   process. Without this capacity, it is altogether useless. Of the
>   characteristics of time, as all men conceive it, viz. as measuring
>   events, as having parts, past, present, and future, and as continuous,
>   the only one which is, in the end, retained by this theory is the
>   last, and that illegitimately; for Bergsonian time is, in fact, the
>   series of irreducible different qualities, which, therefore, can never
>   form a unity or continuity. Much more might be added in criticism of
>   the theory, but these remarks may suffice to show that it is
>   irreconcilable with commonsense, and inconsistent in itself; though
>   highly ingenious, and devised with the best of intentions, viz. to
>   rescue living things, and especially conscious processes from the grip
>   of a deterministic mechanism.
>
> (For a fuller discussion, see Nys, *[La Notion du Temps](https://archive.org/details/lanotiondetemps00nysduoft)* [[pp. 233](https://archive.org/stream/lanotiondetemps00nysduoft#page/232/mode/2up) ff.].)

—R. P. Phillips, *[Modern Thomistic philosophy](https://archive.org/details/modernthomisticp01phil)* pp. [125](https://archive.org/stream/modernthomisticp01phil#page/125/mode/2up)-7